# angular2 multiple apps (mobile + desktop)

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I want to have 2 apps (mobile and desktop) sharing the same installation (config, models, services, etc). Right now I have 2 lazy loaded modules(mobile and desktop). It works, but when I'm on desktop module it's still using some mobile stuff - for example common.chunk is much bigger then without mobile module, but the real problem is that my mobile components extends desktop components, and it't going to common chunk, in other words my common.chunk contains all desktop components!. I also tried to set up my own webpack.config to configure common chunk plugin. The question is, it is possible to build only desktop module? I see like like this

`ng build mobile` - build everything inside mobile folder to dist-mobile
`ng build desktop` - build everything inside desktop folder to dist-desktop. I'm stuck here, any help would be appreciated

Comment: There's a good chance that the project should be separated into two projects.

Comment: @estus thanks, but I found the way, works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

I have created my root routing class like this

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', loadChildren: './desktop/desktop.module#DesktopModule' },
    // { path: '', loadChildren: './mobile/mobile.module#MobileModule' }
];
```

Added this file to .gitignor, while developing I just need to switch commented module to switch on desktop module. On production I just need to create this file on mobile/desktop servers

Works fine, but a little bit ugly, I'm gonna create config file to control the current version in future. If someone need that I will post here

Comment: Can you please help me for this. Am also trying this method, Because of performance issue. And am concentrating on Google page speed Insights. My guess is this method is workable.

Comment: @AbijithAjayan what's your problem? This way worked great for my project

Comment: Hi, I want to know, Where we have to add the window width for call desktop and call mobile view.. Apps.

Comment: @AbijithAjayan 
You can't compile/load an angular  module depends on browser width (if I got you right). My solution works for different apps, let's say app.com and mobile.app.com

Comment: Ok Ok. You are doing subdomain for mobile. And Main domain for desktop.